Asynchronous migrations for django/wagtail
I am working with my friends on wagtail school project, we are working at the same time on our project and making different pages at the same time.  We would need a asynchronous system for migrations of pages.
I have searched and found command dumpdata and loaddata but this seems that it is synchronous only, and it is not possible for two people to have 2 open Merge requests since dumped json files would override each other.
Is there any solution for this problem?

Migrations are essentially asynchronous: the migration files generated generate a DAG, but a node can have multiple children. You can make a merge node that then makes a union of the two. There are some small caveats w.r.t. data migrations, but typically these can be fixed by adding extra depdencies.

willeM_ Van Onsem can you please clarify what would be the extra dependences that you have mentioned.

in the migration file, there is dependencies = [...] section, you simply can add extra migrations that need to run first.
